# Implement asynchronous calls in .NET Remoting

Tags: .net, multithreading, asynchronous, remoting

I want to implement async call in .NET remoting. The remoting service is consumed by a windows application ( dont ask me why not WCF. This is a legacy application). Is there any standard procedures, standard patterns to implement.

Comment: Sorry, Just learnt how to use SF!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0sa925ka.aspx